# How to get userId from Firestore on Node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to firebase and I am having trouble setting up the user profile route on my app. Im trying to make it so that the userId stored in Firestore can be retrieved and all the posts made by that specific user will be displayed on the user profile page. Please any help would be appreciated!

This is my Firestore database :

[image]

and this is what I have so far but it is not displaying all the posts associated with the user id

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const firestore = require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firestore.getFirestore();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("No user id provided");
});

router.get("/:uid", (req, res) => {
  const uid = req.params.uid;
  const userPost = firestore.getDoc(firestore.doc(db, "reviews", uid));

  userPost(uid, req.query && req.query.dev === "true")
    .then((user) => {
      return res.send(user);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return res.send(e);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

This line gets the single (probably non-existant) post at `/reviews/:uid`:

```
const userPost = firestore.getDoc(firestore.doc(db, "reviews", uid));
```

What you are looking to do is build a query for documents in the collection `/reviews` where `docData.userId = uid`.

```
const reviewsColRef = firestore.collection(db, "reviews");
const userPostsQuery = firestore.query(reviewsColRef, firestore.where("userId", "==", uid));
const userPostsPromise = firestore.getDocs(userPostsQuery);

userPostsPromise
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const postsArray = querySnapshot.docs.map(docSnap => {
      const docData = { id: docSnap.id, ...docSnap.data() };
      delete docData.userId; // it's the same for every post, may as well omit it
      delete docData.email; // same as above
      return docData; 
    });
    res.json({ posts: postsArray, count: postsArray.length });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // don't send the full error object to the client,
    // instead you should log the error and send the
    // client as little information as possible
    console.error(`Failed to get user posts for firebase:${uid}`, err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.code || err.message }); // Don't forget to use an appropriate status code!
  });
```

**Notes:**

- I recommend using destructuring to import the Firestore lib. Importing it as `firestore` negates the benefits of the modular SDK of only importing what you need.

```
import { getFirstore, query, collection, ... } from "firebase/firestore";
```

- If this code is running on a server you control, consider switching to the Firebase Admin SDK instead as this allows you to bypass security rules and has relaxed rate limits.

```
import { getFirestore, query, collection, ... } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

- As a side note, if an import from the SDK conflicts with a name you want to use elsewhere, you can rename it. You might see this when using the RTDB and storage together as they both export `ref`:

```
import { getDatabase, ref: rtdbRef } from "firebase/database";
import { getStorage, ref: storageRef } from "firebase/storage";

const userDataRef = rtdbRef(getDatabase(), "users", uid, "data");
const imgStorageRef = storageRef(getStorage(), "path/to/image.png");
```

- Treat emails as sensitive data akin to a phone number. Nobody likes spam and limiting ways to rip emails from your database is good practice. Unless you are working on an internal tool for a corporate network, you should hide the user's email as much as possible.
- Email addresses should not be stored with reviews. Instead keep a collection with documents for each user (e.g. document at `/userProfile/:uid`) and limit access to privileged users.
- Consider adding a `404 Not Found` error when a user doesn't exist.
- Consider adding authentication to restrict access to your API.